# Set ImageView fo ListView Active State

Tags: android, android-listview, activestate

Most apps that **maintain active state** in a menu `listView` also provide a small `imageView` visual in addition to color change.

How would you do this?

Would it be a part of the `state_activated=true` selector somehow, or should it be done programatcally in Java and perhaps in the `ListAdapter`?.

In the image below, you see on the Youtube app, the acte state has BOTH Background image change AND the visual indicator.  (Red Line)

[image]

Comment: See this [ANDROID LISTVIEW : HIGHLIGHT SELECTED ITEM](http://www.michenux.net/android-listview-highlight-selected-item-387.html)

Comment: @AwadKab  Yes, this discussed setting colors for Active State (which I already do), but I want an image in the row to be also set visible if active, but invisible rest of time.

Comment: You can change imageview visibility by code `v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` and `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: I think I need something like this, `if (activestate==position) { // make visible } else { // make invisible }`.  Seems like this would go in `getView()` method in `adapter`.  Not sure how to implement.

Comment: You can do that by make `9 patch` image and use it as background when the row activate.

Comment: @AwadKab  Your comment helped me get it working.  Make that the answer an I'll mark you right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by make 9 patch image and use it as background when the row activate.